Showing $f'(x)/f(x)$ is unbounded when $f(x) \ge 0$ has zero Taylor series at $x = 0$
I’m reading Lee’s Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. When encountering the uniqueness of integral curves (of smooth vector fields), I wonder that why won’t a bump function or a function like $\begin{cases} 0 & \text{, if } x \le 0 \text{,} \\ \mathrm{e}^{-1/x} &\text{, if } x > 0 \end{cases}$ disagree with it. I also recognize that Norton’s dome challenges the uniqueness of Newtonian mechanics. I inspected the case $\mathrm{e}^{-1/x}$ and Norton’s dome, and found that they don’t admit a smooth vector field.
I think we can directly prove it for general cases, and I formalize it as:

Let $F \colon (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to \mathbb{R}$ be an smooth increasing function that $F(x) = 0$ for $x \in (-\epsilon, 0]$. Prove that $V$ defined by $V(0) = 0$ and $V(y) = F'(F^{-1}(y))$ for $y > 0$ is not smooth at $y = 0$.

My approach: That is, $V(F(t)) = F'(t)$. We have
$$
V'(y) = \frac{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d} V}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d} F} = \frac{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d} V}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d} t} \bigg/ \frac{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d} F}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d} t} = F''(t) / F'(t) \text{.}
$$
So it suffices to prove that $F'' / F'$ is unbounded as $t \to 0$. (This is checked for $\mathrm{e}^{-1/x}$ and Norton’s dome.)
Let $f(t) = F'(t)$, we have $f(t) \ge 0$ and the goal becomes $f' / f$ unbounded.
I’m not able to finish the rest of the proof. I tried to use the mean value theorem:

For any $x_1 > 0$, we can find an $x_2 \in (0, x_1)$ that $f'(x_2) = f(x_1) / x_1$.
Then repeat this we can find $x_n$ based on $x_{n - 1}$.
Now consider $f'(x_{n + 1}) / f(x_{n + 1})$, which equals $\displaystyle \frac{1}{x_n} \frac{f(x_n)}{f(x_{n + 1})}$.
If we can show that there’s at least one $n$ s.t. $f(x_n) > f(x_{n + 1})$, then by the arbitrariness of $x_1$, we have one $\displaystyle f'(x_{n + 1}) / f(x_{n + 1}) = \frac{1}{x_n} \frac{f(x_n)}{f(x_{n + 1})} > \frac{1}{x_n}$ unbounded.
I’m stuck at showing there’s at least one $n$ s.t. $f(x_n) > f(x_{n + 1})$, as we cannot surely state that $x_n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

If anyone can fix the problem in my proof, thanks in advance. Also, I’m looking forward to a simpler proof, too.
Also, I suggest that this question {Why the derivatives $f^{(n)}(x)$ of Flat functions grows so fast? (intuition behind)} may help(?), but I cannot solely make use of it.

The title doesn't coincide with the question.

@jjagmath May I ask why does the title not coincide with the question?

There is no mention of a Taylor series or analytic functions in your question. You only talk about smooth functions, which not necessarily have a Taylor series.

@jjagmath My bad, all I wanted to mean is that $f$ itself and all its derivatives are zero at $0$.

Though I think Taylor series can be defined for any smooth function...? According to Wikipedia, there’s no need for the function to be analytic. And also one definition of analytic functions is that the Taylor series converges in some neighborhood at all points?

Converges to the function itself ….

@TedShifrin Thanks! *One definition of analytic functions is that the Taylor series converges to the function itself in some neighborhood at all points*

Yes. I would move the “at all points” earlier in the sentence.

It’s very suspicious that @jimmyb posted many answers in a short time, having an obviously wrong answer to my question at first. Isn’t it an LLM-bot?
Nevertheless, thanks to @jimmyb providing a plausible path (in the middle of the answer, the definition of $H(t) = \ln(F'(t))$), although the final argument makes no sense. Now I may proceed:

Let $g(t) = \ln(f(t))$, then $g'(t) = f'(t) / f(t)$.
It suffices to prove that $g'(t)$ is unbounded.
Note that $g(t) \to -\infty$ as $t \to 0$.
Assume $g'(t)$ is bounded around $0$, say $\lvert g'(t) \rvert \le M$.
We have $g(t) = g(t_0) - \int_{t}^{t_0} g'(u) \mathop{}\!\mathrm{d} u \ge g(t_0) - (t_0 - t) M$.
Limiting $t$ to $0$ gives $-\infty = \lim_{t \to 0} g(t) \ge g(t_0) - t_0 M$, a contradiction.

